# How to do a simple `Date.today` in my Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, irb

When I execute the command `Date.today` in my rails command, I get the following error:

I can't do a simple `Date.today` in my Rails console

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :026 >   >> require 'date'
 => false 

ruby-1.9.2-p180 :027 >   >> Date.today
ArgumentError: invalid date
    from /Users/besi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/date.rb:809:in `civil'
    from /Users/besi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/Date.rb:1810:in `today'
    from (irb):27
    from /Users/besi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/besi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/besi/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/besi/Dropbox/projects/Freelance/vidis/VidiServer/script/rails:6:in `require'
    from /Users/besi/Dropbox/projects/Freelance/vidis/VidiServer/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

In the irb console this works without problems:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > require 'date'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > Date.today
 => #<Date: 2013-04-15 (4912795/2,0,2299161)>
```

Comment: Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.13.rc2)
1.9.3p392 :001 > Date.today
 => Mon, 15 Apr 2013 
Hmmm. Not sure.

Comment: Did the `require 'date'` return `false` when it was used the first time itself, or was this a subsequent `require`?

Comment: @RoneyMichael The first one returned false. It looks like there is a problem with my IDE (RubyMine) plugin. In the terminal I can get the date.

Comment: So, other `require`s return `true`, do they?

Comment: @RoneyMichael No, also subsequent `require 'date'` return false in my IDE. In the Terminal.app the first one returns `true` and then `false` as you would expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with the RubyMine Plugin here. When I do the same thing in the console it works. I don't know though why such a simple thing should not work in RubyMine.